# Communication between directives (and other parts) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm looking for guidelines about when and why should I use the "require" option in the directive definition,
why not communicate just using the Scope - like most of the times in Angular ? 
How is it, that suddenly in directives, I ask for the controller itself and not just attaching things to the scope(s) ?

Generally speaking - there are many ways to communicate between directives/controllers/scopes in Angular -

- Scope inheritance.
- RootScope "emits".
- Services (factory/service/provider).
- Requiring controllers in directives.
- Requiring new Scope/ isolate scope / "normal" scope in directives.
- More?

And while I understand how they work technically, it's not clear to me what are the guidelines to decide which one to use and why.

Will be happy for some general/high level guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` is particularly useful if you want to create [custom form controls](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) (see section *Implementing custom from controls*) -- i.e., you want to create your own form control with a directive.  You can `require` the [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController) to get access a lot of existing functionality via its API/functions.

Another use case is found on the AngularJS home page, section *Create Components*, where the `pane` directive uses `require: '^tabs'` to get access to the `tabs` controller.  Since both of these components/directives create isolate scopes, scope inheritance is not an option.  A service wouldn't be a good fit either, since your app could have multiple `tabs` directives.  So, in this case, the controller is used as a means for the `pane` directive to be able to affect the `tabs` scope -- to be able to get at the scope.  Without using `require`, the `pane` directive can't get at the `tabs` scope.  I discuss this in more detail (with a picture) in this SO answer: ['this' vs $scope in AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699)

`require` can only be used if the controller-of-interest is defined on the same element (e.g., `ngModelController`), or if there is a hierarchy (e.g., pane -> tab).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will also read the other discuss you've directed me. "Since both of these components/directives create isolate scopes, scope inheritance is not an option." Even in isolate scope we can use '@' or '=' and get some inheritance, I guess the problem with that is still inheritance collides with tabs/panes higher in the scope chain ? or I get it all wrong ?

Comment: @Daniel, true, '@' or '=' could be used, but this would require that the `pane` directive be passed attributes via HTML -- i.e., the `addPane()` method would need to be specified for every use of pane: `<pane add-pane="addPane()" ...>`.  So using `require` seems to be a cleaner approach here.